# Setting up XNAT in Amazon EC2/Google Compute Engine

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, amazon-ec2, google-compute-engine, xnat

I want to set up a [XNAT](http://www.xnat.org/) instance "in the cloud".

I don't have experience with EC2 or GCE. I'd need to setup the following to get XNAT running:

- Java jdk 1.6+
- Tomcat 6+
- PostgreSQL 8.4 +

I've found tutorials on setting up Tomcat in EC2, but not on setting it up in GCE. Searches for "[Tomcat](https://developers.google.com/search/results?q=tomcat&p=/compute)" and "[PostgreSQL](https://developers.google.com/search/results?q=postgresql&p=/compute)" in GCE's site provide no results. Why?

Answer (score 1):

From the Compute Engine side, we offer supported images for several Linux distributions including Debian and Centos. Once you have an instance (VM) running, it is a standard operating system, so tutorials for Debian or Centos should work fine for configuring software on Compute Engine.

One area where you'll likely need an extra step is on the networking side. By default all TCP ports are blocked on Compute Engine, except for port 22 for SSH. See the [documentation for adding a firewall](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#addingafirewall) for details on how to open up other ports for your software.